# split function doesn't return

Tags: java, function, split

```
String str ="|m4oho5kspqikkfn2may72osnfzmn3gutwzqctblzqy6rygwzxbra6bjkmy|113|70|";
String[] tokens = str.split("|");

System.out.println(tokens[0]);
System.out.println(tokens[1]);
```

result in white::
0

I just need this
But the only thing I want to come back is: m4oho5kspqikkfn2may72osnfzmn3gutwzqctblzqy6rygwzxbra6bjkmy

Sorry not be much English I am using Google Translator

Comment: Escape `|` by using `.split("\\|")`.

Comment: consider using `StringUtils.split()` -- it is null-safe, faster than by regex and easier to use

Comment: split uses regex, and in java regex, `|` is an `OR` operator. To split based on literal `|` character, you need to escape that character for the regex parser with `\ `, and considering java itself uses `\ ` as an escape character, you need to "espace the escape-character" in this case. So try `str.split("\\|");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is a regex protected character. You need to escape it when splitting like so:

```
str.split("\\|");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can find more detailed information for regex expression in the java doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

There are a lot of really good examples. I strongly recommend to check them.

For literals you must use double backslash (\) to escape the escaped character.

Cheers.